# git clone --mirror confusion

Tags: git, clone, mirror

I'm submitting a some sample work to a potential client, they have provided specific instructions on how to submit it, but their instructions have me confounded.

These are the exact instructions:

```
Please do not post your fix on public git repositories, instead please work 
locally.

1. mkdir fix && cd fix
2. git init
3. touch README.md
4. git commit -m "Initial commit"
5. < ...fix, fix, fix... >
6. cd .. && git clone --mirror fix fix.repo
7. tar czf fix.repo.tar.gz fix.repo
```

If I follow the exact instructions, I end up with a compressed file containing just the repo, and none of the actual files. As you might infer, I am no git guru, but I can easily see that my actual code is around 12MB and the uncompressed "deliverable" is under 300KB.

Does anyone have any idea regarding what might be going on?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a lot of files in your "working area" that you never committed to the git repository.

On step #5 as part of writing the code, etc. you should save the code in the Git repository by committing it.

See steps `07` and `08` below.

```
01. mkdir fix && cd fix
02. git init
03. touch README.md
04. git add README.md
05. git commit -m "Initial commit"
06. < ...fix, fix, fix... >
07. git add .
08. git commit -m "Everything fixed"
09. cd .. && git clone --mirror fix fix.repo
10. tar czf fix.repo.tar.gz fix.repo
```

If that's the case, I'd recommend spending some time learning how Git works.

- https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1
- https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-git

Comment: Great! FWIW, in that case you could run `git clean -fxd` on your original repository to clean all the files being ignored by git first, before doing the mirror clone

Answer (score 0):

The culprit was a log directory deep down in the bowels of the existing code, filled with needed uneeded .zip files which were being ignored by the commit. I wasn't aware of their existence :(

Once I rehydrated the clone with: "git clone file:///home/derek/fix.repo/ /home/derek/test/restore" I re-ran my code from that location, was able to see the issue and create a handler to create empty zip files to appease the beast.

If I hadn't tested it like this, my submission would have crashed and burned upon being run by the client...